# Codeigniter and RESTserver. Send and receive in JSON format

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building an API using Codeigniter and Phils RESTServer.
I want to send a bounch of email addresses to the API (best in JSON format).

How can I do this? How can I "receive" and "use" the JSON object that is sent to the server?

Right now I can send and receive parameters like this:

```
email=example@example.com
```

and I receive and use them like this:

```
$this->post('email')
```

I want to send and receive in this format instead

```
{"email":"example@example.com"}
```

How can I achieve this and how can I use the object?

**UPDATE**: I at least need to be able to send a normal array to the RESTserver.

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1):

There is an output class in codeigniter. For json encode, you can use this:

```
 $contents = $this->output
                  ->set_content_type('application/json')
                  ->set_output(json_encode(array('email' => 'example@example.com')));

 echo $contents;//{"email":"example@example.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about posting the JSON string to the controller and then using json_decode() to extract the data out if it?

```
$data = json_decode($this->post('json'));
echo $data['email'];
```